# Write Itunes metadata to mp3 files

Tags: itunes, mp3, metadata

I'd like to write all the metadata I have in Itunes to the mp3, including album art, lyrics, etc. Itunes does not do this, I tried with other programs and none of them could actually read the metadata I had added in Itunes.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes does this for me. I tell it copy files to my media library and keep them organized for me, I'm not sure if this is the reason why. The metadata is all set for me in all files.

Comment: iTunes also writes metadata to my files, and that metadata is viewable by 3rd party apps.